# How to get the number of physical and logical cores in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

`WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors` gets me most of what I want, but how do I store the output into a variable?

Also, in the case of a dual socket machine, will this return all combined cores?

Comment: roro, please don't spam a comment to each of the responders, especially when your question is a completely different one to the main one in your initial post. I would advise that you remove your comments below each of those answers, and [edit] your question to remove the second question. Then select the most suitable answer for your initial question, mark it as accepted, _(and upvote any other notable ones if you feel it warranted)_. Then post a new question complete with your new specific dual socket output information, _(and properly formatted)_.

Comment: The initial question explicitly asks about dual sockets, no answer addresses it. Why shouldn't a comment be duplicated if it's valid for both answers? Answerer's will not be notified of comments on someone else's answer.

Comment: roro, questions should be limited to one per posting. Your question is about getting the result of a specific command, _(which you submitted)_, and asks how to store that result to a variable. Your additional query is whether your submitted command, will return all combined cores. Your question most certainly was not a single off topic request for a fully coded solution to determining individually, the number of cores for each socket of a multi-socket computer, and save each to separate individual and identifiable variables, or to combine all results into a single variable adding each together

Comment: Yes, I am. This site helps you to fix a single specific and replicable issue with your submitted code. For that, you submit a [mcve] of that code, provide any information for us to to run it, to exhibit that issue, and include, along side it, all possible output and debugging information. At that point we can attempt to help you to fix your code. You have not submitted code to reproduce a specific issue, you submitted working code, asked how to do manipulate it, despite that having been answered thousands of times here before, and introduced an additional problem you'd like that code to cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a command's output, use a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /value"') do set /a "_%%a"
set _
```

Parsing `wmic` output has some quirks (Unicode, strange line ending `CRCRLF`), and there are several methods to get the format you want. As here the values are purely numeric, I chose `set /a`. This won't work if the values are alphanumeric.

Attention:
`NumberOfCores` gives you the number of cores, not the number of physical processors. There are single- and multicore processors. The number of physical processors can be obtained with:

```
wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM get NumberOfProcessors,NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

(please double-check, of `NumberOfLogicalProcessors` matches the value given by `WMIC CPU`. I don't have a multiprocessor system available to check)

Comment: For dual socket machines the WMIC command returns

```NumberOfCores=24
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=48

NumberOfCores=24
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=48```

How can the core count for each socket be stored?

Comment: Do you expect different types of processors on the same board? I might be wrong, but as far as I know, on a multiprocessor system, all processors have to be identical.

Comment: I believe you're correct, but I have equal amount of trouble getting an increment to work in the for loop. Is there a better way of getting the cpu count?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2delims==" %%b in ('"WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /value"') do set /a "%%b=%%c" 2>nul
SET numberof
```

The two WMIC report lines of interest have format `item=value`, `value` is numeric so `set /a` can be used. The `2>nul` suppresses the errormessages generated by processing the other lines.

note that there is also a system-established variable `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS`

---

Revised in light of comment

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
For %%c IN (numberof count) DO FOR /F "delims==" %%b In ('set %%c 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%b="
for /f "tokens=1,2delims==" %%b in ('"WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /value"') do (
 set/a count%%b+=1
 set /a "%%b[!count%%b!]=%%c" 2>NUL
)
SET num
pause
```

The `for...%%c` line simply clears any existing variables with names starting either `numberof` or `count`.

The code in the `for...%%b` interprets the `WMIC` output for the elements that are of the form `name=value`, assigning `name` to `%%b` and `value` to `%c`.

First, it increments (say) `countNumberOfCores`, then it assigns the value in `%%c` to the variable `NumberOfCores[currentvalueof"countNumberOfCores"]`

Comment: For dual socket machines the WMIC command returns

```NumberOfCores=24
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=48

NumberOfCores=24
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=48```

How can the core count for each socket be stored?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be on a system without wmic (like some versions of Windows 11) you can use powershell to do this in a batch script:

```
set "_numCores="
for /f %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor -KeyOnly -Property NumberOfCores | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NumberOfCores" 2^>nul') do set "_numCores=%%g"
if defined _numCores echo Number of Cores: %_numCores%
echo Number of Logical Processors: %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%
```

Note: Now simplified with Compo's helpful suggestions.

Edit 2: I made a couple additional edits thanks to Compo's suggestions. Feel free to use his style of coding. The main point here is that you may need to rely on a different method to invoke WMI if a system does not have WMIC. An alternative might be javascript.

Comment: There is no point in trying to determine the location of `powershell.exe` within the `%PATH%` or the current directory, if you are not doing anything if it is not located. You should undefine the varaible `psLoc` before your initial `for /f` loop, the `where.exe` command should redirect stdErr to the NUL device, and then after the loop you should determine whether the `psLoc` variable is defined before you continue to run code which can only work successfully with it correctly defined. Also there is no need to use `-ExecutionPolicy` with a PowerShell 'command', only with a PowerShell 'file'.

Comment: As a follow up to your edited answer, using `ft`/`Format-Table` seems slow and excessive here, and using `(GCim Cim_Processor).NumberOfCores` would almost certainly be less speedy than something like the following: ```@Set "_numCores=" & For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor -KeyOnly -Property NumberOfCores | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NumberOfCores" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "_numCores=%%G"```. You could then follow up with ```@If Defined _numCores Echo Number of Cores: %_numCores%```

Comment: For dual socket machines the core count for each socket is printed:
```
NumberOfCores
-------------
           24
           24
```

How can the count for each socket be stored?