# How to get the number of physical and logical cores in a batch file on a dual socket machine?

Tags: windows, batch-file

`WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors` gets me most of what I want, but how do I store the combined output into a variable?

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /value"') do set /a "_%%a"
set _
```

Works for single socket machines only. The `WMIC` command returns cpu info on separate lines, i.e.

```
>WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /value

NumberOfCores=24
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=48

NumberOfCores=24
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=48
```

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71861185/how-to-get-the-number-of-physical-and-logical-cores-in-a-batch-file that you already asked today?

Comment: There was stern feedback to close and ask again with minor changes about the dual socket part

Comment: I've edited my answer to your previous question, but have no multiprocessor system to check. Please revisit and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /A "_NumberOfCores=_NumberOfLogicalProcessors=0"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores^,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /value') do if "%%b" neq "" set /A "_%%a+=%%b"

set _
```

Note that `wmic` command output lines terminated in CR+CR+LF ASCII characters, even the empty lines, so it is necessary to check if the `%%b` part exists to avoid to process empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a in ('WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores^,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /value /format:csv') do set "both=Cores=%%a Processors=%%b"
```

`/format:csv` changes up the format some, making it easier for us to manipulate, which I did in the above command.

Comment: This seems to execute `set "cores=24"   & set "processors=48` twice where I would like to get the total sum, i.e. cores=48 and processors=96

Comment: @roro You should learn how to manipulate basic variables. I edited my answer to do what you said.